# Dynamically generating regression coefficients and tracking their change over time

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, regression-coefficients

I'm running a generalized linear model (quasi-poisson regression) as a cron job in R that trains on data from an SQL query. The SQL query pulls data from the last 30 days. Depending on the sample of data from the last 30 days, the regression coefficients of course change. As a result, I'm then writing the regression coefficients generated in R back to an SQL table, with year/month/day as the the primary key. Thus, I can see the daily change in regression coefficients based on the most recent 30 days of data.

My question is this: how do I best interpret the change in regression coefficients over time?

If I can see a broad overview of techniques, I can hopefully find the one most appropriate given my data.

My objective is to reduce the RMSE of a predictive model. The response variable is the number of events in the 30 day interval from the current time. I have multiple predictors, including interaction terms.

Edit: it is not a requirement to only query the last 30 days of data. I simply wish to weight data closer in time more heavily. A discrete-time (days, in this case) weighted regression on all data would probably be ideal.

Comment: I hope you're also recording the standard errors of parameter estimates as well as information about temporal correlation of those errors, for otherwise you may have quite a bit of trouble distinguishing real changes from changes due to random fluctuations.

Comment: I've noticed that temporal correlation of errors is a given a lot of attention in econometric/time series analysis texts. Should I focus on time series analysis methods? Maybe since I'm creating a time series that's self evident, but I'm just wondering which field best deals with my issue.

Comment: (1) If your 30-day windows overlap, benrolls, then they will share data. This creates strong correlations among the parameter estimates. (2) In light of your edit, some confusion may be created because typically a "linear regression" predicts a numerical value; predicting individual events (or counts) requires more sophisticated generalizations of linear regression. You might get more focused answers if you could offer a little more information about your model and its objectives.

Comment: BTW, what you are doing is very close to a one-dimensional version of [geographically weighted regression](http://ncg.nuim.ie/ncg/GWR/whatis.htm): perhaps studying that procedure may give you some guidance.

Comment: "The weighting scheme is organised such that data nearer (u,v) is given a heavier weight in the model than data further away." In my case, distance from (u,v) is simply distance in time from present, with data closer to present time being given a heavier weight. This is really what I am trying to achieve: continually weighting data closer in time more heavily to improve a predictive GL model.

Answer (score 2):

First you want to know if changes are just due to noise in the data.  For that you want to look at the estimated standard deviation for the regression parameter estimate. If the estimates seem to fluctuate around a constant and stay mostly within the 2 sigma limits it is probably random variation.  If all the data were kept you would be seeing the variance of the estimate get smaller and tend to 0 but since you always only keep the last 30 days the variance should stay roughly constant. If you are testing for a change in th coefficient such as a drift upward or downward I think that control chart approaches might be appropriates (e.g. cumulative sum charts).  However the method would need modification because with control charts the data is assumed to be independent.  But if you sum repeated estimates of a regression parameter they would be highly positively correlated.